# Green's Fuction- Execise 1

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

**EXERCISE**

> Find Green's function $G(x,y:x_0,y_0)$ of the problem:
>
> $ΔG(x,y:x_0,y_0)=-δ(x-x_0)δ(y-y_0), x, x_0\in \mathbf{R} , y, y_0 \in (0,\infty)$
>
> $G(x,0:x_0,y_0)=0, x\in \mathbf{R}$

**To tell the truth I don't know even how to start this exercise as I don't have any experience in this kind of exercises.**

*So how can I solve this exercise?I know that I haven't done any attempt here but I really don't how to use green functions in these exercises!*

**I would really appreciate a thorough solution and explanation or any hint here since I've just started working on these problems.**

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: This the Green's function for the half plane with the Dirichlet boundary condition. You can use the method of image charges to figure it out. See [here](http://physics.gmu.edu/~joe/PHYS685/Topic2.pdf) for the 3D example. All you have to change is to figure out what the 2D Green's function is for the Laplacian.

Comment: Sorry, I saw your link and thank you, but I didn't figure it out. Can you elaborate?